# Why does Excel give me a #NAME? error when I open this CSV file?

Tags: excel

The CSV file has two lines, one header and one data.
Here it is in Notepad and Excel.
[image]

Here's CSV text:

```
XGID,Id,Structure,With?,Equity Loss,Player,Match,Game,Move,Board

XGID=-b----E-D---dD--ac-da---AA:0:0:1:62:5:2:0:9:10,343628903392,0 000005 040000 400000 000001 1,With,0.055999999999999994,"Ben Friesen","Ben Friesen (5.55) - Herb Roman (7.86) 9pt Michigan 2016",5,3,-b----E-D---dD--ac-da---AA
```

Comment: since you have a minus sign (`-`) in front of `b` it tries to convert to something numeric, so Excel doesn't recognize `b` as a variable for example. You need to force it to understand it as text. Probably adding as a prefix: `'`will solve the issue, probably there is some other option to force Excel to read it as text.

Comment: Adding a double quote doesn't help. Adding a single quote fixes the error, but the single quote appears in the cell - sort of second best.

Comment: *.csv files are best **imported** using either Power Query (available in Excel 2010+)  or the Legacy Wizard. You can then define the column types (as text) and this should obviate the problem. Double-clicking on the file merely allows Excel to make a guess as to data types, and it often guesses incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing your `Text to columns`, continue the wizard until you can choose to set the datatype for each column.

There, scroll to the last column and choose `Text` as data type.

If Excel splits your CSV automatically at start, just choose the cell and remove the `=` sign before the text because this is what makes it behave like this.

No need to add `'` in this case.

Comment: When I open Excel and do a Data | From Text/CSV, the data comes in without a problem. But when I double-click on the CSV file in Explorer, then the problem appears. It'd be nice to have a solution that works for double-clicking.

Comment: Indeed, it's the second part of my answer. Couldn't find how to do that automatically but I believe just removing the `=` doesn't do it for you right ?

Comment: If you examine the CSV file, you'll see there is no equal sign.

Comment: I know, it is being added by Excel because it tries to guess the type of the column. Here it guesses a numeric since it starts with `-`, thats why the removal should happen after having opened the file